# A script for checking whether any odd number is in the form 2p+q

Tags: python, list, algorithm, primes

I want to make a python script that can check whether any odd number is on the form 2p+q, where p and q are two primes, this is my script but i don't know why it doesn't work

```
prime1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
prime2 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

def isit(x):
    for p in prime1:
        for q in prime2:
            if x == p+2*q or x == q+2*p:
                return 'It is'
            else:
                return 'It is not'
 
print(isit(7))
```

It is obvious that `7=2*2+3`, but the script that i've wtitten said 'It is not', so why it doesn't work, it looks quite good for me.

Comment: Your script returns if the first thing it tries doesn't work.

Comment: How can i fix that @Samwise

Comment: Side note: you don't need to duplicate the set of primes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return "is not" until you've tried *all* of the combinations.

```
for p in prime1:
    for q in prime2:
        if x == p+2*q or x == q+2*p:
            return 'It is'

return 'It is not'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check p = 2 and q = 2!
Then your script returns 'It is not'.